# Do I need a X11 server on server machine to do X11 forwarding from the client?

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I am new to the fundamentals of X11 Forwarding. Suppose I have two machines:

1. A "headless" ubuntu server, no X, just the CLI.
2. A full ubuntu, with the Desktop and the whole GUI.

Now suppose that I want to use *X11 Forwarding* to display in the machine #2 (the machine with GUI) a Firefox that is running on machine #1. For that I connect from #2 to #1 using *SSH X11 Forwarding*. I don't want to use VNC.

The question is, do I need to have a X11 server running in machine #1? If so, *xvfb* is an option? What requirements do I need to have in machine #1? Just `apt-get install firefox` and thats all?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's your answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6205/must-an-x11-server-be-installed-for-x11-forwarding-over-ssh-to-work on StackExchange.